# Import named destinations in PDF file

Tags: pdf, latex

I know we can export named PDF destinations (hypertargets of external links, like we can reference them in LaTeX with `\href{myfile.pdf#page.42}{link text}`) in Linux with the command line `pdfinfo -dests`.

But how can we add/create such named destination links, in a ready made PDF file we receive from somewhere, with a command line tool?

Comment: Do you mean adding bookmarks? You might look for the pdf operator(?) `pdfmark` which can be used with ghostscript. There aren't many examples.

Comment: @meuh, named destinations/link targets in pdfs are not the same thing as bookmarks

Comment: Thx @meuh, your comment still helped very much in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the hint from @meuh, pointing to Adobe's PDF [pdfmark](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_pdfmark.pdf) feature, I found that the job of importing the (potentially hand crafted) pdfmarks (for using things like named destinations like they would be created by LaTeX `\hypertarget{}` and more) from a file can then be done via ghostscript like:

`gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFDontUseFontObjectNum -dPrinted=false -sOutputFile=FILE_NEW.pdf FILE_ORIGINAL.PDF PDFMARKS_TO_BE_ADDED_TO.ps`

…suggested by the man page of the `extractpdfmark` program ([included in a number of Linux distros](https://pkgs.org/download/extractpdfmark), source code at https://github.com/trueroad/extractpdfmark), which does the job of showing/exporting all the pdfmarks (navigation links, named destinations, …) of one PDF file as a postscript PS file, which than can be re-imported to other files via above `ghostscript` command line – e. g. for use cases where an original file contained the destinations, which then get lost during some in between processes, and must be re-imported (like it is in my full use case, I did not describe in detail because that part seemed not relevant here).
After that import one then can (again) successfully link to that file's specific PDF pages from LaTeX.

Following code snippet might ease the process for the described use case:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# copy pdfmarks from a SOURCE_FILE .pdf to the existing TARGET_FILE .pdf

SOURCE_FILE=$1
TARGET_FILE=$2
PDFMARKS=$(mktemp)
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)

extractpdfmark "${SOURCE_FILE}" > "${PDFMARKS}"

cp "${TARGET_FILE}" ${TMPFILE}

# combine exported PDFMARKS with the content of the TARGET_FILE into the TMPFILE copy of the target file
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFDontUseFontObjectNum -dPrinted=false \
    -sOutputFile=${TMPFILE} "${TARGET_FILE}" "${PDFMARKS}"

cp ${TMPFILE} "${TARGET_FILE}"
```

---

(Just adding this, because in many conversion processes of my experiences unwanted side effects appeared: Also things like annotations done via Xournal or Okular are after adding the pdfmarks still there like before, but bookmarks/ToC do not seem to get taken over, maybe use `pdftk`'s `dump_data` feature for that.)

---

Another note: to generate some simple destinations for a PDF just create a file, e.g. `pdfmarks.ps`:

```ps
% manually crafted
[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /DOCVIEW pdfmark
```

Then run a command line snippet:

```bash
for i in $(seq 1 999); do 
    echo  "[ /Dest (page.$i) /Page $i /View [/Fit] /DEST pdfmark" >> pdfmarks.ps
done
```

to generate hypertargets as named destinations for 999 pages, which you can than use with above ghostscript command to add it to another PDF. (Note that for PS it is intended, that the first opening square bracket in a line is not closed at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps isn't the best way, but you could do that with LaTeX itself, using a combination of the `pdfpages` and `hyperref` packages.

Suppose you had a PDF named inputfile.pdf. You could add some named destinations to it by creating a wrapper for it like this, using `\includepdf` with the `picturecommand=` option containing `\hypertarget` commands.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

% put two named destinations on page 1
\includepdf[pages=1,
    picturecommand={
        \put(100,100){\hypertarget{mydestination2}{}}
        \put(200,250){\hypertarget{anotherdestination3}{}}
    }
]{inputfile}
% put a named destination on page 2
\includepdf[pages=2,
    picturecommand={
        \put(200,100){\hypertarget{yetanother}{}}
    }
]{inputfile}
% put rest of pages as is with only page number targets
\includepdf[pages=3-]{inputfile}

\end{document}
```

The `\put(x,y)` commands will put the target at a certain place on the page relative to the bottom left. These are the same or at least very close to the numbers you see when using `pdfinfo -dests`.

The targets of the form `page.###` will be inserted automatically so you get those "for free" as it were.

If you want to do it from the command line without creating an intermediate LaTeX file, the `pdfjam` utility is basically just a wrapper around LaTeX with the `pdfpages` package. So you could use something like this:

```
pdfjam --preamble '\usepackage{hyperref}' --picturecommand'*' '{\put(300,300){\hypertarget{destname}{}}}' inputfile.pdf --outfile outputfile.pdf
```

To put a named destination at 300x300 in the first page of `inputfile.pdf`. See `pdfjam --help` for more information on doing more advanced things.

The real downside to either of these methods is that they don't preserve any destinations that may have already been there. I assume this is many useful, however, for PDFs that don't already have them, and you could perhaps script re-inserting the old ones with a combo of `pdfinfo -dests` and this method.

Comment: Thanks for the nice workaround idea, still the `pdfmark` feature seems to be in conjunction with `ghostscript` the right way to do it, where it would also be possible to generate a file with the needed named destinations via some script, if no base document for an initial export of them exists.